# Import XML to Mysql Parameter Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, xml, stored-procedures, import

I have a problem with the following stored procedure.. 
I'm trying to read a xml from a stored procedure.

When I run the stored procedure I get 0 row ( s ) affected ..
Someone can help me with this problem ;). I was following the example below:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/importing-xml-data-into-mysql-tables-using-a-stored-procedure.html

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `import_applicant_xml`(
    path varchar(255), 
    node varchar(255)
)
BEGIN
declare xml_content text;
declare v_row_index int unsigned default 0;   
declare v_row_count int unsigned;  
declare v_xpath_row varchar(255); 

set xml_content = load_file(path);

-- calculate the number of row elements.   
set v_row_count  = extractValue(xml_content, concat('count(', node, ')')); 

-- loop through all the row elements    
WHILE v_row_index < v_row_count DO                
    set v_row_index = v_row_index + 1;        
    set v_xpath_row = concat(node, '[', v_row_index, ']/@*');
    insert into applicants values (
        extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[1]')),
        extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[2]')),
        extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[3]'))
    );
END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

call import_applicant_xml('C:\\applicants1.xml','/applicant_list/applicant');
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<applicant_list>
  <applicant id="1" fname="Rob" lname="Gravelle"/>
  <applicant id="2" fname="Al" lname="Bundy"/>
  <applicant id="3" fname="Little" lname="Richard"/>
</applicant_list>
```

Action:

```
20:51:01    call import_applicant_xml('C:\\applicants1.xml','/applicant_list/applicant')    0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec
```

[image: Path Xml file]

Comment: Check the path of your XML once

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. Can you get the contents of the variable `xml_content`?. To obtain the value of the variable `xml_content` you can do something like:

```sql
.
.
.
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
.
.
.
  SET `xml_content` := LOAD_FILE(`path`);
  SELECT `xml_content`;
.
.
.
END//
.
.
.
```

My Test:

File: `/path/to/file/applicants1.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<applicant_list>
    <applicant id="1" fname="Rob" lname="Gravelle"/>
    <applicant id="2" fname="Al" lname="Bundy"/>
    <applicant id="3" fname="Little" lname="Richard"/>
</applicant_list>
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `applicants`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `import_applicant_xml`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applicants` (   
    ->   `id`         INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `last_name`  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ->   `first_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL
    -> )//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `import_applicant_xml` (
    ->     `path` VARCHAR(255), 
    ->     `node` VARCHAR(255)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `xml_content` TEXT;
    ->   DECLARE `v_row_index` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `v_row_count` INT UNSIGNED;
    ->   DECLARE `v_xpath_row` VARCHAR(255); 
    -> 
    ->   SET `xml_content` := LOAD_FILE(`path`);
    -> 
    ->   -- calculate the number of row elements.   
    ->   SET `v_row_count` := ExtractValue(`xml_content`,
    ->                                     CONCAT('COUNT(', `node`, ')')); 
    -> 
    ->   -- loop through all the row elements    
    ->   WHILE `v_row_index` < `v_row_count` DO
    ->     SET `v_row_index` := `v_row_index` + 1;
    ->     SET `v_xpath_row` := CONCAT(`node`, '[', `v_row_index`, ']/@*');
    ->     INSERT INTO applicants
    ->     VALUES (
    ->       extractValue(`xml_content`, CONCAT(`v_xpath_row`, '[1]')),
    ->       extractValue(`xml_content`, CONCAT(`v_xpath_row`, '[2]')),
    ->       extractValue(`xml_content`, CONCAT(`v_xpath_row`, '[3]'))
    ->     );
    ->   END WHILE;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `import_applicant_xml`('/path/to/file/applicants1.xml',
    ->                             'applicant_list/applicant');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `last_name`,
    ->   `first_name`
    -> FROM
    ->   `applicants`;
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | last_name | first_name |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Rob       | Gravelle   |
|  2 | Al        | Bundy      |
|  3 | Little    | Richard    |
+----+-----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry I've been busy these days on other things..


I get from xml_content = " null"; 
I think the problem is the file path;

I have made your suggestion, but do not understand the path " / path / to / file / applicants1.xml " where is that file, I have my xml file in C : // .. What direction is that " / path / to / file.applicants1.xml " . Can you help me with that?

Comment: @ElvisAlfredo: Check [LOAD_FILE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).